# Open Sentinel-1 products using ENVI 5.3

Tags: envi, sentinel-1

Is it possible to open `Sentinel-1` products using `ENVI 5.3`?

`GeoTiff` `Sentinel-1` images can be opened independently but I can't open the product (from its `xml` file) using ENVI. I mean, is `SARscape` necessary to open Sentinel-1 products? or is `ENVI` enough for that.

I guess that for the `calibration` and other specific operations, `SARscape` could become a necessity.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *open Sentinel-1*? If you are referring to `GeoTiff` you are most likely using the **GRD** products, which are delivered as `.SAFE` format. You can treat these like a folder and extract the `GeoTiffs` from inside it and open them with ENVI like you would any other raster image.

Comment: @Kersten I meant to open the product (folder in `.SAFE` format or the `zip` file directely) without extracting the `GeoTIFF` files from the `measurements/` folder and reading them individually.

Comment: And what is the specific advantage of doing that over opening each GeoTiff individually? The theoretical maximum in a `.SAFE` container is 4 raster images, and that would require QuadPol acquisition mode.

Comment: @Kersten Just to get the metadata and the `tie point grids` (map of `incident angles`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could open, visualize and process SENTINEL-1 image with SNAP (open software from ESA) http://step.esa.int/main/download/. You must have a very good machine.

Answer (score 1):

Both [Sentinel-1](https://eos.com/sentinel-1/) and [Sentinel-2](https://eos.com/sentinel-2/) imagery can be accessed with [LandViewer](https://eos.com/landviewer). You may download the data in numerous formats such as KML, SHP and GeoJSON and export it wherever needed. Besides that there are dozens of built-in tools available for deep image analysis.